# SLComposeViewController initWithServiceType failed to get extension error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter

I am using Facebook and Twitter share in one of my application. Suddenly while testing, I started getting below following error. I checked my code and it looks okay to me.

```
2017-04-29 14:41:19.727248 iCamTranslator[1140:322770] [core] SLComposeViewController initWithServiceType failed to get extension for identifier com.apple.share.Facebook.post
2017-04-29 14:41:19.727642 iCamTranslator[1140:322770] [core] SLComposeViewController dealloc <SLComposeViewController: 0x102992050>
2017-04-29 14:41:19.750499 iCamTranslator[1140:322770] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <AboutViewController: 0x102986900>.'
```

Here is my code. Note that error occurs for both Facebook and twitter share but I am writing code for only Facebook share as both errors are similar.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };

    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
    [controller setInitialText:@"iCamTranslator is a great translation app."];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icamtranslator/id955853183?mt=8"]];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-2.png"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This stupid error was caused because I have not updated my Facebook app on my device. After updating, everything start's working fine. Sorry for bothering you guys.